# Using pulseaudio with mpd: libpulse not found

Tags: ubuntu, pulse-audio, mpd

I'm trying to build and install mpd to work with pulse audio, so I'm running:

```
./configure --enable-pulse
```

but the last lines read -

```
checking for PULSE... no
configure: error: PulseAudio output plugin: libpulse not found
```

I'm not too familiar with all these packages, but running pacmd opens up the CLI for pulseaudio properly.

Is libpulse something different? How can I get it setup on Ubuntu Maverick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to install the `libpulse-dev` package. It contains the development headers that you need to compile mpd against `libpulse`.

```
sudo apt-get install libpulse-dev
```

This is quite common with many packages; Debian-based distros, like Ubuntu, commonly separate out the runtime components (binaries, shared libraries, image assets, and the like) from the development components (header files, mainly). The pattern is usually to append `-dev` to the package name.